# temporary roofing repair

Tags: leak, roof, waterproofing, patch

Ok so we have a shingle roof that needs to be replaced. We are having some lumber logged off to pay for the repairs. We need to make it for about another 3 months. I was planning on using half inch pressure treated plywood and screwing it down with the roofing screws for metal roofing, caulking around the edges with henry wet patch caulking, and putting the caulk around each of the screws. So my question is will it be ok to screw plywood over the top of worst leaks and caulk the edges till we get the roof replaced? Or rather will this repair last for the three months we need?

Comment: I would think that some rolled roofing installed in horizontal overlapping strips starting from the lower edge of the leak area would be a much better temporary solution that mucking around with the plywood idea. Rolled roofing will be much better to seal to the existing shingles at the ends of the strips and along the top edge of the upper most run. It may very well be lower cost that the plywood and is certainly more adaptable to size of area to be covered in a temporary way.

Comment: Will this work even if the decking underneath is rotted?

Comment: Michael Karas, this could be an answer as it would be a way better way to seal the leak for a few months with less work.

Comment: Ok thank you. And do i just seal the edges with tar and nail it down?

Comment: @CodyPace - It would really depend upon how rotted and how big of area. Hard to really provide the specific guidance you are wanting over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that some rolled roofing installed in horizontal overlapping strips starting from the lower edge of the leak area would be a much better temporary solution than mucking around with the plywood idea.

Rolled roofing will be much better to seal to the existing shingles at the ends of the strips and along the top edge of the upper most run. It may very well be lower cost that the plywood and is certainly more adaptable to size of area to be covered in a temporary way.

Rolled roofing is normally installed in such a way that the lower edge is top face nailed with exposed nails. The upper edge is then nailed but the next strip comes along with some overlap and will cover up that upper row of nails.

Use good old google to search with "rolled roofing installation" for links to sights and videos on the subject.

**Note:** If your roof has large areas with severely rotted roof decking use great care when navigating around on the roof to avoid crashing through and risk of serious injury.

Comment: I put the rolled roofing on covering an area much larger than the leak. The leak in my ceiling is about a 3x4 square and i covered an 8x8 space above the leak on my roof. Unfortunately it didn't help the leak. So i think now I am going to place a tarp from the top edge of the last run of rolled roofing all the way over the crest of the roof.

Comment: Leaks often happen on a roof not where the visible leakage damage shows inside the dwelling. Leaks can travel along roof valleys, between shingles, drip along framing members and flow along ceiling materials. Sometimes it is necessary to climb up into the attic to inspect from under the roof to spot where the real leak is. Interestingly I had a damp inner wall I though was due to a roof leak. I replaced the roof (which was due for replacement anyway) and the damp wall persisted. In the end it turned out to have been due to a pin hole leak in copper plumbing which one day went full spray.

Comment: I have a mobile home so i don't have access to the attic. Any way i can tell without actually being in the attic?

Comment: Next to impossible except for ripping open the ceiling or the roof itself.